# on click make a server request to change php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I thought I solved the issue in a preceding question but it is sill not working. I want to change the php variables ($start and $end called by var b1 and var b2) if the admin clicks on button. After this the new code should be availble for every visitor, so it should make a server request. Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
  if(date('w') == 4){ // day 2 = Tuesday

$start = strtotime('9:30');
$end = strtotime('12:30');
$timenow = date('U'); 
if ($timenow >= $start && $timenow <= $end) { 
 echo'<div id="iar_eu">';
echo quick_chat(200, 'default', 1, 'left', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
 echo'</div>';
 } } 
 ?>

</div>



<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Start Chat" id="start_chat" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 10px;" />
<?php
 } ?> 

  <script type="text/javascript">



if(jQuery('#start_chat').data('clicked')) {
   // change var b1 and b2
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/web/htdocs/www.fattorefamiglia.com/home/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/chat.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { b1: "1:00", b2: "23:00" }
}).done(function(data) {
    b1 = data.b1;
    b2 = data.b2;
});}

else {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/web/htdocs/www.fattorefamiglia.com/home/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/chat.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { b1: "9:00", b2: "18:00" }
}).done(function(data) {
    b1 = data.b1;
    b2 = data.b2;
});}



jQuery('#start_chat').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);

  var b1 = '<?php echo $start; ?>';
  var b2 = '<?php echo $end; ?>';

});


</script>
```

chat.php:

```
<?php
// variables
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $data['b1'] = $_POST['b1'];
    $data['b2'] = $_POST['b2'];
}

// to not lose them
$_SESSION['chat'] = $data;

// to keep it compatible with your old code
$start = $data['b1'];
$end = $data['b2'];

// send the JSON formatted output
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the request/response with an addon such as firebug in firefox or the developer tools in chrome?

Comment: with firebug it gives me this: jQuery('#start_chat').click(function(){
$(this).data('clicked', true);
var b1 = '1348133400';
var b2 = '1348144200';
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```js
if(jQuery('#start_chat').data('clicked')) {
```

will never be true since `.data('clicked')` is not set until `#start_chat` is clicked which always will happen after the check has been made.

You need to rethink your process of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: thanks! I understand now. any advices on how should I proceed?

Comment: You want the click of the button by one user to make all users see the other/new thing? If so, you need to store that trigger globally, either in a file or in a database and read in that value on every load. Check the following tutorial for how to handle things with files in PHP, http://www.developer.com/lang/php/article.php/1146721/Using-PHP-with-Files.htm

Comment: First, you don't start any session in your code (it might be started automatically though). Then you set the `$_SESSION['chat']` which is good. But then on the other PHP page you refer to `$start` and `$end` which you haven't declared on that page from breaking up `$_SESSION['chat']`. Also, `$_SESSION` **is only for the current user, not all users** that you are going for, therefor it can not handle what you want of it. So back to files or database as I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the way jQuery is being used. All jQuery references should be made in functions that are only called after the page is ready, or in a wrapper that makes sure the page is ready.

For example, this code needs to be wrapped:

```
jQuery('#start_chat').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
  var b1 = '<?php echo $start; ?>';
  var b2 = '<?php echo $end; ?>';
});
```

Like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#start_chat').click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    var b1 = '<?php echo $start; ?>'
    var b2 = '<?php echo $end; ?>';
  });
});
```

Setting the `.data()` isn't going to do you any good here. You're setting some info to the actual var instead of the element because of the way that method works.

But there's another problem with the way you're deciding to make AJAX requests, simply putting an if statement there won't make it happen. You would need a listener to make an action actually happen. But rather than get into that why don't you just simplify and do it like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var b1 = '<?= $start ?>', b2 = '<?= $end ?>';

$(function(){
  $('#start_chat').click(function(){
        $.post('/web/htdocs/www.fattorefamiglia.com/home/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/chat.php', { b1: '1:00', b2: '23:00' }, 
            function(data) {
                b1 = data.b1;
                b2 = data.b2;
            }, 'json');
  });
});
</script>
```